# Add row to tableview to add row and core data

Tags: uitableview, core-data

I've created a navigation controller based application that uses core data.  Without modifying much of the code from the starting application first, I'd like to be able to add rows by having the option to add rows via a dynamic row after I push edit.

Other examples I've found such as the one found at [this site](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-DeleteandaddrowfromTableView.html) show the desired functionality however it does not use core data, so I haven't been able to translate this correctly using core data.

I've looked at the sample application iPhoneCoreDataRecipes and that application includes the desired functionality, however the sample is incredibly complex.  Based on the sample app, i've added the following to my - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath function

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
// For the Ingredients section, if necessary create a new cell and configure it with an additional label for the amount.  Give the cell a different identifier from that used for cells in other sections so that it can be dequeued separately.
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:0];

NSInteger rows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]; 
NSUInteger ingredientCount = rows;
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

if (indexPath.row < ingredientCount) {
    // If the row is within the range of the number of ingredients for the current recipe, then configure the cell to show the ingredient name and amount.
    static NSString *IngredientsCellIdentifier = @"IngredientsCell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IngredientsCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        // Create a cell to display an ingredient.
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:IngredientsCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

   // 
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
} else {
    // If the row is outside the range, it's the row that was added to allow insertion (see tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:) so give it an appropriate label.
    NSLog(@"---- IN ADD INGREDIENTS SECTION ----");
    static NSString *AddIngredientCellIdentifier = @"AddIngredientCell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AddIngredientCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Create a cell to display "Add Ingredient".
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AddIngredientCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Add Ingredient";
}
return cell;
}
```

When I click the edit button I can delete rows, however I'm not getting the added row to click to add rows.  The sample app is much to complex to tell what i'm missing.  Is there a function to add to automatically add the 'add row' button the end of the table?

**EDIT:**  Added all of my .M file for reference @ http://pastebin.com/Ld7kVts7
When I run my NSLog's 1-12 show in the console.  I'm not currently trying to add the "add row" row to core data because that row is added or removed every time the user pushes the edit button in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed your the `numberOfRowsInSection` method of your datasource to account for the extra row that you need?

Comment: Yes.  the number of rows in section method contains the following   `id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
   
    NSInteger rows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    if (self.editing) {
        rows++;
    }
    return rows;`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add the new object to your database, then, assuming your tableView's dataSource is an array form your database, call reloadData on the tableView.